# How to define mail from address in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im trying to send mails from SMTP using Spring boot,
In laravel this is my code, which works

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@outlook.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mail@2021
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@outlook.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="YourName"
```

this is the Spring boot code

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.username = mail@outlook.com
spring.mail.password = mail@2021
```

Outlook says, i need to define mail from Address, i did it in laravel, whats the Mail from address for Spring boot ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.from=test@test.com
```

Notice that the email must exists, otherwise, you will get an error.